# open a new window, and call javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I would like to know how a new window can be opened from a javascript method, and then call it's javascript methods.

The url of the window, is in another domain (can cause a security problem !?), and I don't have control over it.

For example, a code that should behave as the followings:

```
handler<-openAWindow("www.someurl.com");//open a window and get a handler for it
handler->someMethod1(param1, param2);//call some javascript method 
handler->someMethod2(param3, param4);//call some other javascript method<br>
```

Thanks,
Eran.

Answer (score 17):

You cannot control or access a cross domain window unfortunately. This is done for security precautions. Do you have control over the other URL?

However, if the window is on the **same domain** you do have access to the window and its DOM.

```
var win = window.open("/page", "title");
win.someFunction();
var el = win.document.getElementById("id123");
//etc.
```

Comment: @Sarfraz: Well, unfortunately for him at least. But yes, it's best that this precaution was implemented otherwise people could do a lot of naughty things. :)

Comment: This did not work for me, since win.someFunction() would not be ready/defined yet straight after creating the new window - so I had the new window call window.opener.child_ready(), which in turn would run win.someFunction(). If there's a better way, glad to hear about it, otherwise maybe this will help someone.

Comment: @MSpreij, that did help me. I had a situation where I had to pass an ID to a separate page, but not using POST or GET. It sets window.note_id = 1, then runs window.open() and the opening page tests for presence of window.opener.note_id. If it exists, it processes what I need it to do. Thanks for the suggestion, it helped me get where I needed to go.

Comment: To access the document element of a new window, I had to use `yourVariableName.content.document`. And to access the document element of an iframe, I had to use `yourVariableName.contentWindow.document`. But I was not able to execute a JavaScript code that reads DOM content and compares it to a specific value, even on the same domain name. In fact it looks like we can only print values in the web console but not store it in a variable. So I ended up using a Greasemonkey script.