# Is it possible to link/scroll to a location in a page that doesn't have id'ed/name'ed anchors?

Tags: html

There are similar questions on SO, but this one is unique because I have no access to the code I am linking to. I often share links to other pages when giving answers on SO, forums, IRC, etc. Rather than having to say, "Follow [this link](https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#/article/23480523) and search for the 5th occurance of the word 'reminder'." I'd like to just link directly to it. I always view source and look for tags with `id` set or (rarely ever seen anymore) anchors with `name` set. But, if I don't find any, I don't know what to do.

**UPDATE:** Just like every other question on SO and result I've found on Google, I'm already getting responses that assume writing code or installing something. So, let me be very clear:

> *If you can't actually post an example link here on SO, then it is not a solution.*

**Digression:** There should be a standard for searching/scrolling/highlighting in URLs. Perhaps http://example.com/#/reminder/[5] would scroll to (and highlight would be nice) the 5th occurrence of 'reminder'.

Comment: Not sure if something like that exists, but it seems within the realm of a browser plugin or grease monkey type app... Id start there..

Comment: You can totally do this, you can scroll to any thing that you can find the position of using [`Element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), But you should include an example of what you've tried, and what the specific programming issue is.

Comment: "no access to the code I am linking to" - doesn't `Element.scrollTop` require access to the js on the target page?

Comment: @ToniLeigh You can run javascript on a page opened by the current page. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772535/open-a-new-window-and-call-javascript-function

Comment: @TinyGiant - top answer says it isn't possible for XSS reasons, am I missing something?

Comment: @ToniLeigh Ahh, I wasn't thinking about cross-domain. This doesn't actually use cross domain javascript, but you can use PHP's curl to get the contents of the page and reshow the content on a page on your own domain, then access the copy http://stackoverflow.com/a/17262334/4639281

Comment: Though this isn't a yes to the question, because you would have to use PHP, and you aren't actually referencing the real document, but just a copy of it.

Comment: FWIW, pretty much every question I ask on SO gets an answer of "that's impossible". If something is difficult, I figure it out. If it's hard as hell, I find an answer before asking a question. If I can't find an answer and have to ask a question, there probably isn't an answer. That's the curse of the effective engineer.

Comment: the only solution would be to suggest this to the browser makers ...