# How to apply a GoogleSheet Filterview via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I have created some Google Apps Script code which creates GSheets `FilterViews`. I cannot see how to apply a specific `FilterViews` (not `Filters`) to the current sheet.

The code I have sets FilterSettings and then applies it to a basic filter but I cannot see in the documentation how to apply a similar approach to filterview.

```
if (condition!=0 && hiddenValues.length>0)
  {
    filterSettings['criteria'][COLUMNS.ASSIGNEE.pos] = {
      'hiddenValues': hiddenValues,
      'condition': condition
    };    
  }
  else if(hiddenValues.length>0)
  {
    filterSettings['criteria'][COLUMNS.ASSIGNEE.pos] = {
      'hiddenValues': hiddenValues,
    };    
  }
  else if(condition!=0)
  {
    filterSettings['criteria'][COLUMNS.ASSIGNEE.pos] = {
      'condition': condition
    };    
  }
  
  // Using BASIC FILTER not FILTER VIEW   
  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  }

Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
```

Have looked at this doc:-

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#FilterView
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ConditionType
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ConditionValue

I can see that historically its not been supported but I wonder if that is still the case.

I can see if i look at the requests API there are request types for:-

- addFilterView
- deleteFilterView
- updateFilterView
- duplicateFilterView

There is no SetFilterView.

What is the right way to activate a filter view via GAS.

Comment: For one thing, FilterViews are not global i.e., One user can have a different filterview, while another user can have a different view. This is not the case with filters. This suggests that filter views are done local in the browser. Probably cannot be applied from server side.

Comment: Not convinced about that. You can select a filterview via the fvid param on the url.

Comment: Then if you can use a modal dialog/sidebar/webapp to open the sheets app(``window.open``), you can control the params from  the web-app.

Comment: Agreed. But that would spawn a new window each time i needed to pass new params. Im looking for a solution where i can just apply the filterview to the current sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `FilterView` could not be set from apps script

#### Workaround:

In this workaround, The main con is that, You'd need to open the Google sheets through a url and that url tab/window will run in the background. You can also easily do this with plain `=HYPERLINK()` formulas using the same logic without any apps script.

- FilterViews has the following url hash appended to sheets edit url:
  `gid=SHEET_ID&fvid=FILTERVIEW_ID`
- Publish a web app(`HookService`) for the explicit purpose of opening Google sheets url.
- Using the web-app, It is possible to change Google sheets url.
- Sidebar can be opened in Google sheets with filterview buttons
- Sidebar will then connect to the web-app(through `window.postMessage`) and command it to change Google sheets url. This is needed because sidebar cannot directly change the  Google sheets url, but a web-app can.

#### Sample script:

*WebApp*: **hookService.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><span>Starting</span> HookService on Google sheets....</h1>
    <div id="main">
      <p>This is needed to set filter views</p>
      <p>Kindly allow pop ups to continue....</p>
      <label
        >Your Google sheets ID:<input
          id="sheets"
          type="text"
          value="<?=id?>"
          autocomplete/></label
      ><br />
      <label>Sidebar Origin:<input id="origin" type="url" autocomplete/></label
      ><br />
      <button>START HOOK</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      var win1, win1url;
      let [div, input, origin, button] = [
        ...document.querySelectorAll('div,input,button'),
      ];
      origin.value = window.location.origin;
      function openSheets() {
        win1 = window.open(
          (win1url =
            'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + input.value + '/edit'),
          '_blank'
        );
        if (win1) {
          document.querySelector('span').textContent = 'Running';
          window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
          div.innerHTML = 'Close this window to stop Hook Service';
        } else {
          alert('Pop up blockers must be disabled on this site to run hook');
        }
      }
      openSheets();
      button.addEventListener('click', openSheets);
      function receiveMessage(event) {
        //[SECURITY] Check event origin
        if (event.origin !== origin.value) {
          console.error('origin disallowed');
          alert('Origin not allowed');
          return;
        }
        win1.location.replace(win1url + event.data);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*SideBar*: **hookSubService.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
      div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button id="1">FILTER VIEW 1</button>
      <button id="2">FILTER VIEW 2</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const win0 = window.top.opener;
      if (!win0) {
        alert('Hook service not found! Exiting...');
        google.script.host.close();
      }
      /************TODO: Set sheet ids and filterview ids************/
      const gids = ['Sheetid for filter view1', 'Sheetid for filterview2'];
      const fvids = ['filterviewid1', 'filterviewid2'];

      let div = document.querySelector('div');
      div.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let id = Number(e.target.id) - 1;
        let [gid, fvid] = [gids[id], fvids[id]];
        let message = '#gid=' + gid + '&fvid=' + fvid;

        //TODO:[SECURTY] Provide webapp origin url instead
        win0.postMessage(message, window.location.origin);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Server side code*:**code.gs**

```js
function doGet(e){
var page=e.parameter.page
var out = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page || 'hookService');
  out.id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  return out.evaluate().addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Sidebar').addItem('Show FilterView', 'showSidebar').addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('hookSubService.html')
  )
}
```

- Set sheet Ids and filterview ids above in HookSubService.html
- Publish the web-app from script editor
- Open the web app from the published link
- Web app must be bound to the Spreadsheet's script editor

#### References:

- [Window#postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
- [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Great thanks for the detailed solution. Let me test it!

Comment: @Simon After testing, I found that in most cases, both the webapp and the sidebar runs in the same origin. So, If you're going to use it, You should know that `post/receiveMessage()` is not needed and you can directly access/call the webapp hook from sidebar.

Comment: Ah ok. How does that change the code you have provided?

Comment: @Simon So, all parts related to `receiveMessage` are not needed in `hookService.html`. In `hookSubService`, win0 is the webapp. So, instead of calling postMessage on win0 `win0.postMessage(message, window.location.origin)`,  You'd do `win0.win1.location.replace(win0.win1url+message)`. Basically, all variables functions present in `win0` would be freely accessible in the sidebar. I didn't test it, So I'm not editing my working answer now. Related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772535)

Comment: @Simon To be clear, This doesn't change the outward/user facing workflow in any case. You'd still need the webapp to open the Google sheets and run in the background.