# How to apply a FilterView to a Gsheet via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created some Google Apps Script code which creates GSheets `FilterViews`. I cannot see how to apply a specific `FilterViews` (not `Filters`) to the current sheet.

The code i have sets FilterSettings and then applies it to a basic filter but i cannot see in the documentation how to apply a similar approach to filterview.

```
if (condition!=0 && hiddenValues.length>0)
  {
    filterSettings['criteria'][COLUMNS.ASSIGNEE.pos] = {
      'hiddenValues': hiddenValues,
      'condition': condition
    };    
  }
  else if(hiddenValues.length>0)
  {
    filterSettings['criteria'][COLUMNS.ASSIGNEE.pos] = {
      'hiddenValues': hiddenValues,
    };    
  }
  else if(condition!=0)
  {
    filterSettings['criteria'][COLUMNS.ASSIGNEE.pos] = {
      'condition': condition
    };    
  }

  // Using BASIC FILTER not FILTER VIEW   
  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  }

Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
```

Have looked at this doc:-

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#FilterView
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ConditionType
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ConditionValue

I can see that historically its not been supported but I wonder if that is still the case.

I can see if i look at the requests API there are request types for:-

- addFilterView
- deleteFilterView
- updateFilterView
- duplicateFilterView

There is no SetFilterView.

What is the right way to activate a filter view via GAS.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a GoogleSheet Filterview via Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785797/how-to-apply-a-googlesheet-filterview-via-google-apps-script)