# How to add hyperlink to cell in google sheet sidebar addon

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, google-sheets, hyperlink

This [shared spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OAk5oiMRct2UK_6AhK9mxTEZCO9D17NSeEVkHaH_UPU/edit?usp=sharing) has a side bar (opened via the custom menu *Extensions Menu*)

The side bar displays a list of cells within the spreadsheet.
Currently hard coded `A1`,`A2`, ... (in `SideBarTemplate.html` in the script Editor)

Is it possible to make a link to a specific cell ?

The last line displayed in the side bar *This is HyperLink test to A1*
is an attempt to use an href tag with a link to A1 (`href="#gid=1744285851&range=A1"`)
but this is not working.

Side Bar image:

[image]

GAS code:

```
function onOpen(){

  addMenu();
  
}

function addMenu(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'ShowSideBar', functionName: 'showSideBar'}
    ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu ('Extensions Menu', menuItems);
}


function showSideBar(){
  // Display a sidebar with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService
                   .createTemplateFromFile("SideBarTemplate");
  
  htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate();
 
  htmlOutput.setTitle('Ext. Side Bar');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
  
}
```

HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
.style1 {
  color: blue;
  
}
.style2 {
color: red;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?var cells = ["A1","A2"]
    for (var i = 0; i< cells.length;i++){?>
   
    <div class="style1">Cell: <?=cells[i]?> <p class="style2">Required: How to make the blue text to hyper link to cell <?=cells[i]}?>
    </p></div>
    
    <a href="#gid=1744285851&range=A1">This is HyperLink test to A1</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: we are only allowed to view the file. We can't edit or see script/add on menu.

Comment: @Marios Fixed. Anyone Can edit.

Comment: Ok. Why do you want this? What do you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @TheMaster this is exactly what I want to achieve. list of hyper links to listed cells. Just for the sake of the example the list is hard coded set to [A1,A2], but it will dynamically be changed in the actual project - displaying predecessors range(s) for the active cell

Comment: @TheMaster There is no special motivation but be user friendly.  Just navigate to the cell, if that is what the user wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63551838/),  the sidebar frame sandbox attribute lacks `allow-top-navigation`  and therefore, it is not possible to navigate the top frame(including hash change).

#### Workarounds:

- Use server side [`range.activate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate()) methods. Using [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication), you can change the active range in google sheets:

  ```
  //client side
  a1buttonElement.addEventListener('click',()=>google.script.run.select("a1"))

  //server side
  const select = e => SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(e).activate()
  ```
- A twisted workaround to bypassing the sandbox  limitation is by  using a web-app. In this case, Google sheets should be opened by a web-app. If it is opened by a webapp, We can exploit the `window.opener` api to write to the `top` frame. See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896727).